# How to translate a NSString object to NSDate quickly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try to get NSDate objects from NSString which I get from sqlite, but there is a time problem. I takes me 130ms every time. And it's insufferable for i have two hundred objects to deal with. So can somebody tell me what i should do. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your code. Are you creating a fresh `NSDateFormatter` every time? Initializing a date formatter is expensive so should only do it once and reuse it as long as the input format doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using `NSDateFormatter`, you should attend to Apple's recommendation, **caching formatters for efficiency**. Instead of creating a `NSDateFormatter` each time you want to convert a date, you should keep a single instance of your `NSDateFormatter`. From [Data Formatting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> **Cache Formatters for Efficiency**
>
> Creating a date formatter is not a cheap operation. If you are likely
> to use a formatter frequently, it is typically more efficient to cache
> a single instance than to create and dispose of multiple instances.
> One approach is to use a static variable.

Comment: I am using NSDateFormatter and create it every time. When I use a global NSDateFormatter object, it just takes 88ms to convert 20 NSString objects. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss:SSS"];
     NSDate *currentdate=[formatter dateFromString:currentdateStr];
 //it returns DateObject If String in Specified Format otherwise Returns nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code block will help you :

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"<Add Your Date Format>"];

        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                        |NSMonthCalendarUnit
                                        |NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                        fromDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString: <Add Your Date String> ]];

        [dateComponent setHour:24];
        [dateComponent setMinute:00];
        [dateComponent setSecond:00];

        <Your NSDate Object> = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent];
```

It might require to change dateComponent values for Hour, Minute, Seconds - according to your calendar time.

Let me know if you face any problem in this..